# Changing Average Formula in pivot table depending on filter

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, ms-office, pivot-table

I have a group of data with the following fields:
Code, Product, Rate, Volume

Each code has multiple products. On each row of the pivot table is a code, and the table has a product filter. The Rate is the value in the table. I want that rate to change depending on a combination of products selected.

E.G. If Code A has:

- Product A, 2% Rate, $1000 Volume
- Product B, 3% Rate, $3000 Volume
- Product C, 1% Rate, $1000 Volume

I want the rate field to display 2.4% when all are selected, 2.75% when A&B are selected, 1.5% when A&C are selected and 2.5% when B&C are selected.

How do I do this? Currently, I am only able to have the rate field display an average or a sum, which is not right. I.E. in the above example, average would display 2%, which is not accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little convoluted, but I think this gets at what you want.

1. In your original table of data, create a helper column that multiplies Rate by Volume. I will refer to this column as Helper.
2. Select your pivot table, then go to `Analyze>Calculations>Fields Items & Sets> Calculated Field`
   [image]
3. Name your new field `Weighted Average` then for your formula enter `Helper/Volume`, then select `Add`
4. Your calculated field will now show the weighted average for each Code based on the filtered Products. It worked for your simple example, I would think it would work for your larger table.

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver. Thank you tons.